# How to automate upload APK from Jenkins to TestFairy

Tags: android, jenkins, apk, testfairy

I could not figure out how to command Jenkins to upload an APK to Testfairy. I know that Testfairy has an API for this, see the link below:

http://blog.testfairy.com/how-to-upload-an-app-to-testfairy-via-api/

I'm new to this, how do I use the API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, according to the documentation you linked, you need to run:
`sh testfairy-upload.sh yourfile.apk`
This also means this is just for *nix OS and maybe Mac, but not Windows.

You need to download their [`testfairy-upload.sh`](https://github.com/testfairy/command-line-uploader/blob/master/testfairy-upload.sh) script and save it somewhere accessible to Jenkins, preferably in the SVN/SCM. Then you need to open that file and modify the top parts of it, namely `TESTFAIRY_API_KEY`, `TESTER_GROUPS`, `KEYSTORE`,`STOREPASS`, and `ALIAS` with your own information.

There are many ways to trigger this after the build, but the most straightforward is to add a **new** build step **after** your APK building step.

- Add **Execute Shell** build step
- Write `/path/to/testfairy-upload.sh ${WORKSPACE}/path/to/yourfile.apk`
- Obviously replace `/path/to/` with actual path (if in local directory, you have to use `./testfairy-upload.sh`). Replace `yourfile.apk` with the artifact of your build, whatever its name is, and provide appropriate path to it (within `${WORKSPACE}`)

If you are on a Windows environment, you would have to re-write that script in Batch

Comment: Actually I got it working on a Jenkins Windows slave using:
bash /path/to/testfairy-upload.sh ${WORKSPACE}/path/to/yourfile.apk

but the fact I installed cygwin and added cygwin/bin to PATH might have had something to do with it.

Answer (score 5):

And now there's a plugin that does the dirty work for you:

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/TestFairy+Plugin